Using wireless headset microphone
Many topics have been opened so far, most of them have not been answered or there seems to be no solution. My question is to be able to use the microphone (HSP/HFP) when the output device A2DP is selected on the Bluetooth headset. I use Galaxy Buds Pro. I want to use it in meetings because it cuts off external sounds, but I can't. While there is no problem with wired headphones connected via jack, this problem also occurs with wireless headphones. It has been a long time since I used wired headphones and we still can't use high quality sound (A2DP) and the headset microphone at the same time on computers. Is there a solution for this?



Correct at the current time you can not have mic and high quality sound over Bluetooth at the same time as many questions on this site have covered.

This question is similar to: Bluetooth headset only plays sound in mono. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
